# How to split column values by comma and return it as an array

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see below I have `Name` column. I want to split it by `/` and return the value in array.

**MyTable**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John/Warner/Jacob |
| 2 | Kol |

If I write a query as

```
Select Id, Name from MyTable
```

it will return

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John/Warner/Jacob",
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kol",
},
```

Which query should I write to get below result ?

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": ["John", "Warner", "Jacob"],
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": ["Kol"] ,
},
```

Comment: How are you getting MySQL to return a JSON String now? Or is that just a randomly bad representation of what you get back from your existing query

Comment: No. Actually, I'm converting the response into `JSON format`. You can ignore `the format`. I'm okay with the format what is returned by `mysql` or `sql`

Comment: You cannot get SQL to return arrays, MySQL has no idea what an array is, nor do any other DB's I know of

Comment: It is better not to use delimited lists in a database column

Comment: This would be better done using some code written around the query and resultset, are you using anything other than MySQL like PHP/etc

Comment: I can't control it unfortunately because DB is designed like it. I don't want to transform it BE or FE as that would be extra load on them. If possible I want to do it using mysql/sql...

Comment: Then you had better start searching the [MySQL String functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: Just converting to JSON format won't do? `CAST(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(Name, '/', '","'), '"]') AS JSON) AS Name`

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can return an array in the query itself, but you could do this...

```
SELECT id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', 1) 
    AS name_part_1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', -1) 
    AS name_part_2
FROM tableName;
```

Only way to build it as an array would be when processing the result accordingly in whatever language you are using.

Comment: OP Just made the question a bit more difficult I am afraid

Comment: Yes a bit @RiggsFolly. Brain thanks for the answer but it is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function `split`, which is based on the fact that `substring_index(substring_index(name,'/',x),'/',-1)` will return the x-th part of a name when separated by '/'.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`SPLIT`(s varchar(200), c char, i integer) RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE retval varchar(200);
  WITH RECURSIVE split as (
    select 1 as x,substring_index(substring_index(s,c,1),c,-1) as y, s 
    union all 
    select x+1,substring_index(substring_index(s,c,x+1),c,-1),s from split where x<= (LENGTH(s) - LENGTH(REPLACE(s,c,''))) 
  )
  SELECT y INTO retval FROM split WHERE x=i ;
  return retval;
END
```

and then do:

```sql
with mytable as (
   select 1 as Id, 'John/Warner/Jacob' as Name
   union all
   select 2, 'Kol')
select
    id, split(Name,'/',x) as name
from mytable
cross join (select 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3) x
order by id, name;
```

output:

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jacob |
| 1 | John |
| 1 | Warner |
| 2 | [NULL] |
| 2 | [NULL] |
| 2 | Kol |

1. It is, of course, possible to refine this, and leave out the NULL values ...
2. I will not convert this output to JSON for you ...